# Does word "расфокусировка" exist?

Tags: лексикон

I was looking for a word meaning "blur" (as a noun) or "bokeh".

I know the word расфокусированный means "out of focus", but does "расфокусировка" exist?

Comment: Shortly, "Расфокусировка" is not "bokeh".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `расфокусировка` does exist, it might be found in the dictionaries. However  it's rather a gerund in English grammar terms, that is it denotes an action and not a state. But i guess depending on a context it might work.

[Here](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=blur) you have a host of translation options. I would prefer `мутность`, `размытость/размытие`, `туман`, `нечёткость` or more accurately `эффект мутности/размытости/нечёткости`

But in my opinion all above mentioned options aren't adequate enough. Russian fails in this department.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Надеюсь, смысл будет понятен с такими примерами.

Comment: Wikipedia thinks a direct loanword `боке` exists, by the way.

Comment: @Oleg Lobachev among specialists it may be known, i, not being a specialist, have only got to know it through this question, and there's very high likelihood that to a regular Russian speaking person it won't tell anything as opposed to `blur` to an anglophone

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Any amateur photographer knows what is `боке`. If you will spend one or two hours for reading any book, article, etc. about photography, you will meet this word.

Comment: @Dmitry sadly i'm not a photographer, even not an amateur, and although i'm familiar with `blur` effect from using graphic editors, with `боке` i hadn't been familiar until i read this question, i believe there're many more people like me than otherwise... obviously i don't dispute it being a jargonism, the disparity is in the fact that the English `blur` isn't strictly a professional jargon, it's comprehensible by any uninitiated person unlike `боке` by any average native speaker of Russian

Answer (score 3):

The simplest google search immediately proves that **such word exists**.

Proof #1. [An article](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) in Wiktionary:

> **расфокусировка** - смещение фокуса, нарушение фокусировки

Proof #2. A photography [tutorial](http://www.fotonotes.ru/?p=47) titled "Расфокусировка — несколько приемов сделать снимок оригинальнее"

Proof #3. A medicine [article](https://okulist.online/zabolevaniya/glaz/narusheniya-refrakcii/rasfokusirovka-zreniya.html) "Что такое расфокусировка зрения, и как ее лечить"

Plus about 90000 other proofs. So, please, in future tend to perform some initial research before asking a question here. The more effort you put into the question, the higher is the probability you'll get quality answers.

Also I want to mention that, while the Russian wiki on ["боке"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5) indeed does not use `расфокусировка` (or just **`расфокус`**) to my knowledge it's quite common term in professional photographers community.

Comment: the OP doesn't ask if `расфокусировка` exists but if it exists as a legitimate translation for `blur` which is a purview of terminology not easily parseable by a non-native speaker

Comment: indeed, the user does, still, it can be easily googled and this is also mentioned in my answer (link to photo tutorial plus explanation how this used by photographers)

Comment: OK, I admit that I didn't look for the word "расфокусировка" directly on Google's search bar, but even so I consider unfair to say that I did no previous research. I usually check for new words on dictionaries, both printed and online, and the ones I had checked only mentioned "расфокусированный". Hence the question, having also the knowledge of the word "фокусировка" as a reference.
Anyway, thank you for your answer and confirmation.

Comment: @swrutra again, it's not a rant about being lazy or something - 
explanation what sources you've been looking for and why you still have doubts can make things clearer for those who answers. It's all about the quality of question and possible answers.

Comment: I see. Maybe you're asking me to cite sources in future questions and not particularly on this one.
Anyway, my sources for this word were dict.com, openrussian.org, and my printed dictionary (which is from 1989, so it may be a bit outdated when it comes to technological terminology).

Answer (score 2):

Now, to `bokeh`.

I would describe it as `размытие фона` or `фон не в фокусе`. Russian Wikipedia [thinks](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5) a direct borrowing exists, `боке`. This is in my opinion even more professional jargon than `расфокусировка`. (The latter, as I think was already mentioned, is a state of the optics rather then property of the image.)

A more formal term around bokeh is `глубина резко изображаемого пространства` (depth of field), but it describes *everything* on the object in and out of focus. A more formal/professional description of bokeh would then be something like `малая ГРИП с нерезким фоном`, loosely corresponding to `shallow depth of field`, which results in bokeh.

Answer (score 0):

**Расфокусировка** (объектива) is a *widely* used term in optics. It refers to a *position* of lens components, corresponding to blurred image, relatively to the focused position giving the most sharp image. The term can also describe any *motion* in lens components *towards unfocused state* of the lens as does the verb **расфокусирование** which describes *just action*. By extension, the term is often applied to blurred images *resulting* from unfocused state of the lens (*расфокусированность* или расфокусировка *изображения*).